What does "the scripture cannot be broken" mean?
I was listening to a discussion in which someone mentioned that the phrase "the scripture cannot be broken" was a technical phrase used in rabbinic discussions in first-century Judaism, but no explanation was given.  My guess is if that's true then it must mean something like the authority of the scripture can't be negated.
Any help here?

Similar phrasing is used by Jesus in John 10:35 “ If he called them ‘gods,’ to whom the word of God came—and Scripture cannot be set aside”. Offhand I’d agree with your interpretation that it means that you can’t negate or ignore what is written in the scriptures

I'm not sure I agree or disagree with it, but I'd recommend you check out Richard Jungkuntz's article on "An Approach to the Exegesis of John 10:34-36." https://ctsfw.net/media/pdfs/JungkuntzApproachExegesisJohn10.pdf

@Jess  Interesting read.  I note that Jungkuntz holds to the error that the Psalm 82 passage is about human judges, though I don't think that really changes his argument.

In John's gospel we read of Jesus speaking of those unto whom the word of God came, "and the scripture cannot be broken" (10:35). Jesus also said this, "If a man on the sabbath day receive circumcision, that the law of Moses should not be broken..." (7:23). In both cases the sense is clearly that of disregarding or violating the word of God. Yet even if people do disregard or violate the word of God, such "breaking" of it does not adversely affect the solid truth and worth of God's word. God's word remains intact no matter how humans view it, or treat it.
As with stumbling over Christ, the rock-mass, those who stumble damage themselves, not Christ. So with stumbling over the word of God - those who try to break it only break themselves. But those who tremble at God's word know this:

"For ever, O Lord, thy word is settled in heaven." Psalm 119:89 A.V.
"Thy word have I hid in my heart, that I might not sin against thee."
Psalm 119:11 A.V.

This means that no matter what people might do to twist God's word, or to disregard it, or to violate it, or to try to destroy it, they cannot touch that which is settled in heaven. They can sin against it, as do those who have not sunk God's word deep into their heart. But the word of God abides forever.

Insights on the Scriptures - Volume 1 p. 1205 says:

Jesus and his apostles confidently quoted the Hebrew Scriptures as
God’s own word spoken through the assigned writers, hence as certain
of fulfillment and as the final authority in any controversy. (Matthew
4:4-10; 19:3-6; Luke 24:44-48; John 13:18; Acts 13:33-35; 1 Corithians
15:3, 4; 1 Peter 1:16; 2:6-9) They contained “the sacred
pronouncements of God.” (Romans 3:1, 2; Hebrews 5:12) After explaining
in Hebrews 1:1 that God spoke to Israel through the prophets, Paul
goes on to quote from several books of the Hebrew Scriptures,
presenting the texts as though spoken personally by Jehovah God
himself. (Hebrews 1:5-13) Compare similar references to the holy
spirit at Acts 1:16; 28:25; Hebrews 3:7; 10:15-17.
Showing his full faith in the inerrancy of the Sacred Writings, Jesus
said that “the Scripture cannot be nullified” (John 10:34, 35) and
that “sooner would heaven and earth pass away than for one smallest
letter or one particle of a letter to pass away from the Law by any
means and not all things take place.” (Matthew 5:18) He told the
Sadducees that they were in error regarding the resurrection because
“you know neither the Scriptures nor the power of God.” (Matthew
22:29-32; Mark 12:24) He was willing to submit to arrest and death
itself because of knowing that this was in fulfillment of the written
Word of God, the Sacred Scriptures.​—Matthew 26:54; Mark 14:27, 49.
These statements, of course, apply to the pre-Christian Hebrew
Scriptures. That the Christian Greek Scriptures were likewise
presented and accepted as inspired is also clear (1 Corinthians 14:37; Galatians 1:8,
11, 12; 1 Thessalonians 2:13), the apostle Peter in one statement including Paul’s
letters with the rest of the Scriptures. (2 Peter 3:15, 16) Thus the
entire body of the Scriptures comprise the unified and harmonious
written Word of God.​—Ephesians 6:17.

In other words - the term "the scripture cannot be broken" means, "what is written is the undeniable truth from God".

Yes because everything in the world confirms that scripture is true, when people practice necromancy then you check Moses condemned it and many other things

Your quote doesn't actually have the phrase - "nullified" is quite different in meaning to "broken".

https://biblehub.com/greek/3089.htm shows that broken/nullified are both acceptable renderings of the verb used. In the context it basically means that you loosen/annul/break the meaning/purpose - as soon as it would lose it's fulness, it would be broken or rendered meaningless.
